# What is $\hat{H}^*(C_2 \times C_2, \mathbb{F}_2)$ as a ring?

Tags: algebraic-topology, algebraic-number-theory, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

I'm interested in computing the ring structure on the Tate cohomology $\hat{H}^*(C_2 \times C_2, \mathbb{F}_2)$. It's easy enough to compute the ring structure on nonnegative degrees, along with the group structure in general, but I don't know how to extend the cup product to negative degrees. Is the answer known?

Comment: I think this question is covered by https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78287/examples-of-tate-cohomology-rings.

Comment: A bit more detail: I believe that all cup products between negative dimensional elements are zero. I also believe that products between a positive dimensional class and a negative dimensional class are "what you should expect". The link I posted should lead you to some references.

Comment: Thanks. All the links in the thread you mention are dead. I've managed to retrieve the notes of Weiss from an automated archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20130630192620/http://www.math.uwo.ca/~schebolu/research/Jan/tateprop.pdf. The contents seems to answer exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: (For what it's worth, I had no idea what I should've expected. :) )

Comment: A web search turned up Bellezza's thesis for me, too.

Answer (score 0):

Answering for completeness. John Palmieri pointed me at another MathOverflow question which answers what I'm looking for. See [https://web.archive.org/web/20130630192620/http://www.math.uwo.ca/~schebolu/research/Jan/tateprop.pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20130630192620/http://www.math.uwo.ca/%7Eschebolu/research/Jan/tateprop.pdf)